# Sum all integers > 9 individually in R. E.g. 10 = 1+0, 11 = 1+1

Tags: r, function, loops

Im trying to write a function based on the Luhn algorithm (mod 10 algorithm), and I need a function that sums all integers > 9 in my number vector individually. E.g. 10 should sum to 1+0=1, and 19 should sum to 1+9=10. Example code:

```
nmr <- ("1_9_8_2_0_5_0_1_3_3_4_8")
nmr <- strsplit(nmr, "_")
nmr <- as.numeric(as.character(unlist(nmr[[1]])))
luhn_alg <- c(0,0,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,0)
x <- nmr*luhn_alg
x
[1]  0  0 16  2  0  5  0  1  6  3  8  0

sum(x)

[1] 41
```

I dont want the sum of x to equal 41. Instead I want the sum to equal: 0+0+1+6+2+0+5+0+1+6+3+8+0=32. I tried with a for loop but doesn't seem to get it right. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to split the data again after multiplying it with `luhn_alg`.

```
Luhn_sum <- function(x, y) {
  nmr <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, "_")))
  x1 <- nmr*y
  x1 <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x1), '')))
  sum(x1)
}

nmr <- ("1_9_8_2_0_5_0_1_3_3_4_8")
luhn_alg <- c(0,0,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,0)
Luhn_sum(nmr, luhn_alg)
#[1] 32
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring` and `seq` to create a vector of single digit numbers, then you only need to do a sum over them:

```
sum(
  as.numeric(
    substring(
      paste(x, collapse = ""), 
      seq(1, sum(nchar(x)), 1), 
      seq(1, sum(nchar(x)), 1)
    )
  )
)
```